# Cannot change href of the footer icons on Pancakeswap

Tags: reactjs, frontend

New with react here. I love the defi world so I'm trying to fork the PancakeSwap frontend from GitHub.

I already figure out how to add my own styling to it, changed de menu items, etc. The only problem I have, is I cant figure out how to change the href of the icons on the footer (Twitter and Telegram).

Anyone can help me? Probably is very easy but I am stuck.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post some code to show what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just had to hide the entire footer to hide those links. There is one more suggestion which can solve your problem to some extend.

On the file views/App.tsx,
you may remove the Menu call.

This removes the header and footer from the pages. But it is easy to reconstruct a new custom Menu like headerbar with the UIKit.

I have searched across the files and I was able to hide only the footer links and not the social icons.

The footer links can be hidden by not passing footerlinks on the Menu component at ./components/Menu/index.tsx:

```
  return (
    <UikitMenu
     .
     .
     // footerLinks={footerLinks(t)}
     .
     .
    />);
```

Or, you may use the Menu component from a UIKit fork at https://github.com/nguyenphu27/pancake-toolkit-testnet. The previous builds was not having a footer and hence this UIKit is not having a footer.

Sorry, I was not able to find a perfect solution within the same UI library.